# Cannot sign a JWT using Elliptic Curve (EC) cryptography

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have generated a private key using Elliptic Curve cryptography:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp521r1 -noout | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt
```

I have used the following Java code to sign a JWT:

```
    String privateKeyPEM = "MIHtAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjBIHVMIHSAgEBBEEmSOGpmkjzKM+uWhya"
        + "Cl6sbSsmROUol4HaDbORnOI6klbEjbCkPEyxKRnrrtrGFShhu7TPPlGDK39f+K3G"
        + "IZhbYKGBiQOBhgAEAJQiOIKV7YmIVI30Y3y1UZIvgZFRviHFWvSiTXEG4IqzHKpF"
        + "jOIYs0rzn1F2zrFHKpmMtZ0Kh5OzyfJsGeu1GZPzANYLZQ9m13Joi3fhGFUgHLNL"
        + "0hsz/HQP89aTa9Qr8QqEP7r/vCvrcoKn9cKPGwRxOFkRgG4FWGv76F/hv+1Cj2Z7";

    byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyPEM);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
    ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

    final JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject("713f42c9-7df5-4271-8b53-112f30936c56")
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, privateKey)
        .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT");

    System.out.println(jwtBuilder.compact());
```

However, the resulting JWT always have an invalid signature:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI3MTNmNDJjOS03ZGY1LTQyNzEtOGI1My0xMTJmMzA5MzZjNTYifQ.MIGHAkFvCPq_BeXvATTN1duKjEf3K_Fja0ueoTuPQHC9kBc828wem7YO0vnlK6PVYXSkBk4gBaD0-OIMY_r-HS7-4-HaBwJCAMbj0k5YsBywMzme_adKTQq7YUsVvyZwGp8aVgX7vxsMhf-WNvQJSg7AG_zQiUaQ4jqtT9ZKzNoU4P5NZIGMDRCh
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Why do you think the signature is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted private key is a PKCS#8 key. From this the following public X.509 key can be derived:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQAlCI4gpXtiYhUjfRjfLVRki+BkVG+
IcVa9KJNcQbgirMcqkWM4hizSvOfUXbOsUcqmYy1nQqHk7PJ8mwZ67UZk/MA1gtl
D2bXcmiLd+EYVSAcs0vSGzP8dA/z1pNr1CvxCoQ/uv+8K+tygqf1wo8bBHE4WRGA
bgVYa/voX+G/7UKPZns=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

If a JWT is created with the posted code, e.g.:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI3MTNmNDJjOS03ZGY1LTQyNzEtOGI1My0xMTJmMzA5MzZjNTYifQ.AE0sx6wHk2xBPkbam24n8NE39qkB0YX4j65DhrWyBKtaQXRMZjuzV78vFir3scfXVolFOf2gpo2K6x_hu0jPz-0IAIMbYQsglePQHQ9OZMSb2XAxKCVXccdvW27QeBov-VGUxxlL-CFNviaPaAGbNny_sc8cRjIF97pDD4KjOPBKkZzt
```

then this can be verified *without problems* with this public key, check it e.g. [here](https://jwt.io/), i.e. the posted code produces a valid signature.

---

On the other hand, the JWT posted in the question:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI3MTNmNDJjOS03ZGY1LTQyNzEtOGI1My0xMTJmMzA5MzZjNTYifQ.MIGHAkFvCPq_BeXvATTN1duKjEf3K_Fja0ueoTuPQHC9kBc828wem7YO0vnlK6PVYXSkBk4gBaD0-OIMY_r-HS7-4-HaBwJCAMbj0k5YsBywMzme_adKTQq7YUsVvyZwGp8aVgX7vxsMhf-WNvQJSg7AG_zQiUaQ4jqtT9ZKzNoU4P5NZIGMDRCh
```

*can indeed not be verified*. The signature of this JWT is Base64url decoded:

```
30818702416f08fabf05e5ef0134cdd5db8a8c47f72bf1636b4b9ea13b8f4070bd90173cdbcc1e9bb60ed2f9e52ba3d56174a4064e2005a0f4f8e20c63fafe1d2efee3e1da07024200c6e3d24e58b01cb033399efda74a4d0abb614b15bf26701a9f1a5605fbbf1b0c85ff9636f4094a0ec01bfcd0894690e23aad4fd64accda14e0fe4d64818c0d10a1
```

and thus *ASN.1 encoded*, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57731) and [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGHAkFvCPq_BeXvATTN1duKjEf3K_Fja0ueoTuPQHC9kBc828wem7YO0vnlK6PVYXSkBk4gBaD0-OIMY_r-HS7-4-HaBwJCAMbj0k5YsBywMzme_adKTQq7YUsVvyZwGp8aVgX7vxsMhf-WNvQJSg7AG_zQiUaQ4jqtT9ZKzNoU4P5NZIGMDRCh). However, JWTs use a signature encoded as *r|s*, see e.g. [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#appendix-A.3.1). If the signature is converted to this encoding, the result is:

```
6f08fabf05e5ef0134cdd5db8a8c47f72bf1636b4b9ea13b8f4070bd90173cdbcc1e9bb60ed2f9e52ba3d56174a4064e2005a0f4f8e20c63fafe1d2efee3e1da07c6e3d24e58b01cb033399efda74a4d0abb614b15bf26701a9f1a5605fbbf1b0c85ff9636f4094a0ec01bfcd0894690e23aad4fd64accda14e0fe4d64818c0d10a1
```

If this is Base64url encoded and used in the posted JWT (instead of the old signature), that is:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI3MTNmNDJjOS03ZGY1LTQyNzEtOGI1My0xMTJmMzA5MzZjNTYifQ.bwj6vwXl7wE0zdXbioxH9yvxY2tLnqE7j0BwvZAXPNvMHpu2DtL55Suj1WF0pAZOIAWg9PjiDGP6_h0u_uPh2gfG49JOWLAcsDM5nv2nSk0Ku2FLFb8mcBqfGlYF-78bDIX_ljb0CUoOwBv80IlGkOI6rU_WSszaFOD-TWSBjA0QoQ
```

the JWT can be *successfully validated*.

Since the posted code generates an RFC compliant JWT (with *r|s* signature), the JWT posted in the question was probably not generated with the posted code (because of the *ASN.1* signature).

---

**Update:** According to the *jjwt* bugtracker there is a bug ([#125](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/125)) that causes the signature to be signed incorrectly with ASN.1. This bug should be fixed with *jjwt 0.7* and would be a plausible explanation for your issue, provided you are working with an affected version (the bug is from 05.2016).
I have tested your code with *jjwt 0.9.1* (from 07.2018), which generates a valid signature, meaning it works.
The current version is *jjwt 0.11.2* (from 06.2020), which also works according to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007598/9014097).
So if you are working with an affected version, it would be best to use a newer / the current *jjwt* version. If this is not possible for some reason you can of course convert the signature manually from *ASN.1* to *r|s* encoding.

Comment: I used version "0.11.2" as basis for my test that works with changed arguments for signWith.

Comment: @MichaelFehr - Probably all _jjwt_ versions after the fix (0.7+) will generate a valid JWT (independent of the old (0.9.11) or new (0.11.2) `signWith` method). The error behavior is so characteristic that the OP will most likely use an affected version. Finally, however, this can only be answered when the OP posts their _jjwt_ version. @kms333, it would be nice if you could post which _jjwt_ version you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My IntelliJ is claiming that the "signWith"-line is deprecated.

So changing your code

```
final JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
  .setSubject("713f42c9-7df5-4271-8b53-112f30936c56")
  .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, privateKey)
  .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT");
```

to

```
final JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
  .setSubject("713f42c9-7df5-4271-8b53-112f30936c56")
  .signWith(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.ES512)
  .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT");
```

is giving this JWT:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI3MTNmNDJjOS03ZGY1LTQyNzEtOGI1My0xMTJmMzA5MzZjNTYifQ.ALFk_BGerAstughF4ssl5eGQmx0mu5jvWb13QB228hAD5g8dwM-NvBsyevCuYUXLBJKzIUdPL-LVwQoPkwIbYrKhACzKwUwRN_v3IX2GIPW2ctTcRGPwA7gUaDWrOtwqcHALSfk20QZXT2TQfOnXX8tv0vhXLK_SnnHH5o1b96sa_HSR
```

As you only provided the ec private key I used OpenSSL to generate the EC Public key and passed the JWT and public key to the Online JWT verifier https://jwt.io/
and got the result "**Signature verified**".

[image]